# tabulator / regex filter case insensitive?

Tags: regex, filter, tabulator

Looks like Tabulator's regex filter is case sensitive. Is there a simple way to make it case insensitive?

Comment: Sure, add `(?i)` at the start of a regex.

Comment: Any way to preset this, so users don't have to type it in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does the trick:

```
column.headerFilterFunc = function customHeaderFilter(headerValue, rowValue, rowData, filterParams){                        
    return rowValue.match(new RegExp(headerValue, 'i')); 
};
```

Comment: I used: `RegExp(headerValue, 'i').test(value);`

Answer (score 0):

```html
function customHeaderFilter(headerValue, rowValue, rowData, filterParams) {
    return RegExp(headerValue, 'i').test(rowValue);
}


var columns = [
     { title: "MyColumn", field: "fieldName", sorter: "string", headerFilter: true, headerFilterFunc: customHeaderFilter }
]
```

The main answer results in an error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'match')" if the column contains any null values. Robert M. Münch's comment to his answer should be used which resolves this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).